# In Rails, is there a way to scan files uploaded by carrierwave for malware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

How can we scan the images uploaded by Carrierwave for malware? I use it to only upload images. Is it necessary? If so, is there any gems I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a gem for that, but you can scan files for malware using [clamscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clamscan)

It will look like this

```
if system("clamscan #{path_to_temp_file}")
  # save file
else
  File.delete(path_to_temp_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm updating this for future readers but there's now [Carrierwave::AttachmentScanner](https://github.com/attachmentscanner/carrierwave-attachmentscanner) to allow you to scan CarrierWave uploads for viruses and malware (note: this does rely on a third party though Vasile's answer doesn't need any third parties just clamav).

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for [ClamAV](https://github.com/kobaltz/clamby). Drifting Ruby [Screencast](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/antivirus-uploads-with-clamby).

Another gem is [ratonvirus](https://github.com/mainio/ratonvirus).